# Setting form state from object coming from backend response

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have a form with 4 different form controls:

```
this.form = this.formBuiler.group({
    controlOne: ['', Validators.required],
    controlTwo: ['', Validators.required],
    controlThree: ['', Validators.required],
    controlFour: ['', Validators.required]
});
```

I also have a response coming from a service that is a one-to-one mapping with the form object. The keys from the response are boolean values indicating whether the corresponding form control should be marked as invalid or not:

```
{
    controlOneBoolean: true,
    controlTwoBoolean: false,
    controlThreeBoolean: false,
    controlFourBoolean: true
}
```

I'd like to use this state coming from my backend in order to set the form state accordingly and was wondering if there were a clean way of doing so. I was thinking of possibly looping through both objects and setting the `form.get(key).invalid` property to the corresponding value.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you validating server side? You could validate in client side and it would be simpler, I think

Comment: Do these properties match with the form controls... in your question they do not. If they in reality do, it would be much easier :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`setErrors`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#seterrors) method to set error corresponding to a form controller. But in your case response object keys contains `Boolean` as suffix while comparing with form controls names so remove that part and apply error based on value.

```
// assumes validation results in variable `err`

// iterate over the errors
Object.entries(err).forEach(([name, bool]) => {
  // check value is true or false
  // if your condition satisfies set error on controller
  // to get control name remove last 7 character
  if (!bool) this.form.controls[name.slice(0, -7)].setErrors({
    'invalid': true
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `formControls setError` method to set the state coming from backend service.

you can use

`this.form.get('controlname').setErrors(controlBooolean ? 'valid': true : 'valid': false )`

ofcourse you will have to iterate for the response you are getting, here **controlBooolean** is individual item from the backend response

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add validation try this one.

1. **Set** a validator for a control in the `FormGroup`:

   `this.form.get('controlName').setValidators([Validators.required]);`
2. **Remove** the validator from the control in the `FormGroup`:

   `this.form.controls['controlName'].clearValidators()`